# Docusaurus v2 -- how to change images for darkMode

Tags: docusaurus

I'm not very good with javascript so I don't know how to make a image to change in darkMode.

theese images are SVG, and are in the index.js, not in the markdowns.

I've been looking for a way, but the Docusaurus documentation only says how to change the images in the NavBar and Footer..

Answer (score -1):

```css
:root {
    --dev-dash-bg: url("../../static/img/dev-dash-light.png") no-repeat;
    --dev-dash-bg: url("../../static/img/dev-dash-dark.png") no-repeat;
}

[data-theme="dark"] {
    --dev-dash-bg: url("../../static/img/dev-dash-dark.png") no-repeat;
}

.dev-dash {
    height: <desried height>;
    background: var(--dev-dash-bg);
}
```